# Setting selectors for global UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to return a global `UIButton` from a global class.

```
+(UIBarButtonItem *) globalButton {
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40, 40);
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(???)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return myButton;
}
```

So if I call `[Global globalButton]` from my `viewController`, I can get this button. The problem I'm having is how to set the selector, if I'm calling if from my view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do this is below:

```
+(UIBarButtonItem *) buttonWithSelector:(SEL)selector andSender:(id)sender {
   UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   myButton.frame = CGRectMake(-40.0, 10.0, 40, 40);
   [myButton addTarget:sender action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   return myButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem* button = [UIBarButtonItem globalButton];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourDidTapAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

or this in globalButton:

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*)globalButtonWithTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action
{
    // ...
    [myButton addTarget:target action:action
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as follow, assuming you would be calling it from UIViewController

```
+(UIButton *) globalButton:(UIViewController*)delegate {
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40, 40);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gloBalButtonTapped:)])
        [myButton addTarget:delegate action:@selector(gloBalButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return myButton;
}


//Below method should be present in your view controller than only it will be added to myButton click event.
-(IBAction)gloBalButtonTapped:(id)sender{
}
```

You should return `UIButton` only if you are creating `UIButton`, if you need to return `UIBarButtonItem` than you should create `UIBarButtonItem` or Xcode will give warning, just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont add target in **Global Class** wherever you want to use it just use it like this.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [Global globalButton];
btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or you can make **globalButton** a property in **GlobalClass** and write this method in **setGlobalButton** and then you can use it as a property in any viewController.

Or if you want to control it in **Global** only then you can mention your selector mentioned in this class only. And in that method you can control the behaviour.